# Property 'then' does not exist on type Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm new to angular 2 and I'm trying to make a REST GET request, but I'm getting this error when trying:

```
error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<Connection[]>'.
```

Here is the component calling the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router }           from '@angular/router';

import { Connection }       from './connection';
import { ConnectionService }      from './connection.service';

let $: any = require('../scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js');

@Component({
  selector: 'connections',
  styleUrls: [ 'connections.component.css' ],
  templateUrl: 'connections.component.html',
  providers: [ConnectionService]
})

export class ConnectionsComponent implements OnInit {

  connections: Connection[];
  selectedConnection: Connection;

  constructor(
    private connectionService: ConnectionService,
    private router: Router) { }

  getConnections(): void {
    this.connectionService.getConnections().then(connections => {
      this.connections = connections;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getConnections();
  }

  onSelect(connection: Connection): void {
    this.selectedConnection = connection;
  }

  gotoDetail(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/connectiondetail', this.selectedConnection.id]);
  }
}
```

Here is the ConnectionService:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Connection }     from './connection';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ConnectionService {

  private connectionsUrl = 'https://localhost/api/connections';  // URL to web API

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  getConnections(): Observable<Connection[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.connectionsUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure

    let errMsg: string;

    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }

    console.error(errMsg);

    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Thank you,

Tom

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An Observable doesn't have a promise-like method as `then`. In your service you are performing an http call which returns an Observable and you map this Observable to another Observable.

If you really want to use the promise-style API, you need to convert your Observable to a promise using the `toPromise` operator. This operator is not available by default so that you also need to import it once in your project.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Using promises is okay, but there are some good reasons to use the Observable APIs directly. For details, please see this [blog post](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html) advertising the usage of Observables.

If you want to use the Observable API directly then replace your `then` call with a `subscribe` call. But remember that every subscription also needs to be cancelled when your component gets destroyed.

```
getConnections(): void {
  this.subscription = this.connectionService.getConnections()
    .subscribe(connections => this.connections = connections);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Another option when working with Observables is to assign the resulting Observable to a field in your component and then use the [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html). Doing so, Angular will handle the subscriptions for you.

Answer (score 7):

in between add .toPromise() to make it a promise

Answer (score 1):

for Angular I solved it in the following way, I just needed to add the .toPromise method to convert the observer.

```
GetUsersData() {
    const UsuariosCollection = this.afs.collection('usuarios').get();

    UsuariosCollection.toPromise().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id+" => "+doc.data());        
      });
    });
  }
```